# Best way to create this Angular Directive - from / to date selector directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a from / to date selection on my web app as below:

```
<div class="date-picker-horizontal">
    <i class="icon-calendar"></i> 
    Select Date: 
    <input bs-datepicker type="text" ng-model="fromDate" /> to 
    <input bs-datepicker type="text" ng-model="toDate" /> 
    <a class="btn" ng-click="loadData()"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></a>
    <div class="loading" ng-show="isLoading"></div>
</div>
```

I need to use this in multiple places in my web app so I created this as a directive and it is working. I pass in the values from the scope like so:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
   <from-to-date-selector data-from-date="fromDate" data-to-date="toDate" data-on-refresh="loadData()" data-is-loading="isLoading" />
   <from-to-date-selector data-from-date="lastYearsDate" data-to-date="thisYearsData" data-on-refresh="loadYearlyData()" data-is-loading="isYearlyLoading" />
</div>
```

The scope of my controller "myController" contains each variable that is passed to the directive ( fromDate, toDate, lastYearsDate, etc. ) and also the functions to load the data ( loadData(), loadYearlyData() ).

I guess I would like to know if this is the right approach ? I'm fairly new to Angular and don't want to start off by getting into bad habits. Is passing in a whole bunch of values to a directive bad practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any problem with sending variables to the directive, however I'd probably not send "loadYearlyData()" as a function to be executed. It sounds like something that should be on the parent scope, and could be manipulated in the future. Complex data also has a tendency to dramatically reduce the reusability of your directive.

I've spent a decent amount of time building out the date range directive my company's site. I'm putting it here since it may be useful to see another approach.

*Note: This probably is not a perfect answer. It's here to provide ideas and insight.*

Some caveats:

- I use timestamps and all time is UTC
- I use the bootstrap datepicker, with custom modifications to add time (however this works with just a datepicker too)
- I use moment.js for date parsing. I do not inject as a service because I'm lazy.

**Date Range Directive Template**

```
<div class="date-group">
    <input type="text" name="dateRangeStartsAt" ng-model="dateRangeStartsAt" date-start-date="dateRangeMinDate" date-end-date="dateRangeMaxDate" date-time required>
    <span class="text-small text-minor">- to -</span>
    <input type="text" name="dateRangeEndsAt" ng-model="dateRangeEndsAt" date-start-date="dateRangeMinDate" date-end-date="dateRangeMaxDate" date-time required>
</div>
```

**Date Range:**

```
ngApp.directive("uiDateRange", function($timeout) {
    return {
        templateUrl: '/assets/partials/date-range-directive.html',
        scope: {
            'dateRangeStartsAt': '=',
            'dateRangeEndsAt': '=',
            'dateRangeMinDate': '=',
            'dateRangeMaxDate': '=',
            'dateRangeForm': '=',
            'onDateChange': '&',
            'hideTime': '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('dateRangeStartsAt+dateRangeEndsAt', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                // console.log("Change in date", scope.dateRangeStartsAt, scope.dateRangeEndsAt);                   

                if (scope.dateRangeStartsAt && scope.dateRangeEndsAt) {
                    var startsAt = _.isNumber(scope.dateRangeStartsAt) ? scope.dateRangeStartsAt : moment.utc(scope.dateRangeStartsAt + " UTC").valueOf();
                    var endsAt = _.isNumber(scope.dateRangeEndsAt) ? scope.dateRangeEndsAt : moment.utc(scope.dateRangeEndsAt + " UTC").valueOf();

                    var isValid = startsAt < endsAt;
                    if (scope.dateRangeMinDate && isValid) isValid = startsAt >= scope.dateRangeMinDate;
                    if (scope.dateRangeMaxDate && isValid) isValid = endsAt <= scope.dateRangeMaxDate;

                    if(scope.onDateChange) scope.onDateChange();

                    setValidity(isValid);
                } else {
                    setValidity(true);
                }
            });

            function setValidity(isValid) {
                element.find(".date-group").toggleClass("ng-invalid", !isValid);
                if (scope.dateRangeForm && scope.dateRangeForm.dateRangeStartsAt) scope.dateRangeForm.dateRangeStartsAt.$setValidity("dateRange", isValid);
            }    
        }
    }
});
```

**Date Time:**

```
ngApp.directive('dateTime', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) {
                console.warn('no model, returning');
                return;
            }

            var startDate = scope.$eval(attrs.dateStartDate);
            var endDate = scope.$eval(attrs.dateEndDate);
            var api;

            // element.datetimepicker({
            $timeout(function () {
                element.datetimepicker({
                    format: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii"
                    , autoclose: true
                    // , startDate: (startDate) ? new Date(startDate) : null
                    // , endDate: (endDate) ? new Date(endDate) : null
                    , pickerPosition: 'bottom-left'
                });    
            });


            // Angular doesn't update val, do it manually
            if(scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel)) {
                render();
            }

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue) {
                render();
            });


            element.bind('blur keyup change changeDate', function() {
                scope.$apply(read);
            });

            read();    

            function read() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());
            }

            function render() {
                var date = scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel);

                // Convert timestamp to string date                 
                if(_.isNumber(date)) date = moment.utc(scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel)).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm");

                element.val(date);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike, especially for sharing your code. 
From what I can tell ( and I may be wrong ) you are passing the function to run from the parent scope into the directive - '&onDateChange'. This is what I was doing as well.

Was it just the fact that I had called the function 'loadYearlyData()' and that this type of function may not be appropriate that made you mention this may be a bad idea?

Comment: @keithm I think your assumption is correct. My &onDateChange is an optional callback function passed to the directive. With angular, it's usually not in your best interest to use callbacks in this way. A better approach is to attach a $watch to teh attribute in the parent controller. I've in the the callback option in this case because there's usually an outlier or two.

Comment: Mike - thanks again. Could I ask one more thing: If you were to add a button, rather than watch for either the from date or to date changing, how would you do it ?
Are you saying that it's best to add an attribute called, let's say, `doRefreshData` to the directive - and when the button is clicked the directive sets `doRefreshData = true`. I attach a `$watch` to this attribute in my controller and once it changes I refresh the data and set `doRefreshData = false` again ?